# How to Convert ZoneDateTime to Date Object

Tags: java, date

I wan to convert zonedatetime into date object in below format but is not getting specefic timezone related date

```java
ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime2 = ldt.atZone(ZoneId.of("America/Los_Angeles"));
Date datenew = Date.from(zonedDateTime.toInstant());
```

I am getting data in below format but with my timezone not the timezone I passed.

```
Thu Sep 07 17:55:36 IST 2023
```

It should give output in below format

```
Thu Sep 07 05:31:10 PDT 2023
```

Comment: First, if you can avoid using `Date`, do avoid it. It was a poorly designed class and was supplanted by java.time, to which `ZonedDateTime` belongs, a decade ago, so loooong outdated.  If you *do* need an old-fashioned `Date`, what made you believe that you need it to have a specific time zone?

Comment: `java.util.Date` doesn't *have* a timezone. If you're seeing one, it's because another part of the system has applied one (the system default)

Comment: You are asking the impossible. A `Date` cannot have a time zone. It uses your JVM’s default time zone for generating the string to be printed. This confuses many.

Comment: **`java.util.Date#toString`  tells a lie.** That method applies the JVM’s current default time zone while generating its text. One of many reasons to **avoid this class**. Use only the *java.time* classes.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion will try checking java.time api